# dragging of loqSprite object in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i am new to using loqSprite, i am trying to drag a loqSprite sprite object but its not getting done , however it calls its listener only once and then after neither its touch listner is getting called nor even it gives any error, the sprite is playing. Also i thought that might my drag/listener function might be buggy but when i tried the same dragging (movePen() function ) on the inbult corona's Sprite object it works fine. what i am missing i dont know . Can anyone please help me ....  below is the code snippet. thanks

```
local function movePen(event)
   local targetObj= event.target;

        if event.phase == 'began' then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(targetObj);
            targetObj.isFocus = true;
            targetObj.y = event.y;
        elseif event.phase == 'moved' then
            targetObj.x = event.x;
            targetObj.y = event.y;
        elseif event.phase == 'ended' then
           display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil);
           targetObj.isFocus = false;
        end
        return true;
end  --end of touch/move function

local spriteFactoryForPen = loqsprite.newFactory('penAnimation')
local penSpriteAnim = spriteFactoryForPen:newSpriteGroup('pen_write')
penSpriteAnim.x = 100
penSpriteAnim.y = 200

local function spriteEvent (e)  --listener to play in loop 
  if(e.phase == "end") then
    penSpriteAnim:play()
  end
end -- end of sprit event function

penSpriteAnim:addEventListener("touch", movePen); -- adding listener to move pen object
penSpriteAnim:addEventListener("sprite", spriteEvent) -- adding listener to play in loop
penSpriteAnim:play('pen_write') -- playing pen Sprite
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need to call penSpriteAnim:play() in loop. Because it will automatically play in loop untill you don't call the penSpriteAnim:pause() function.

For your touch listener, You should declare all the local variable on top of the page.
I am not sure about this, but hope this will work. Because lua is compiling top to bottom.